# Do these have the same meaning: "Lisa Marie, also a singer, was rushed to the hospital." AND "Lisa Marie, herself a singer, was....."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, reflexive-pronouns

This is from the BBC. [lisa](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-64255117)

***Lisa Marie, also a singer, was rushed to hospital earlier on Thursday.***

The expression **"...also a singer...."** in the sentence is interesting and reminded me of another usage having the same meaning.

*Lisa Marie, **herself a singer,** was rushed to hospital earlier on Thursday.*

I think it has the same function, but not absolutely sure as I am not native speaker. So I wanted to ask, are they the same in meaning.

Comment: BBC News [& other have the same report verbatim] re death of Lisa Marie Presley - https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-64255117 …so, yes, the father was a singer too.

Comment: I think the ***also a singer*** version absolutely *requires* that some recently-mentioned person (presumably *Elvis*, here) is or was a singer. But the ***herself a singer*** wouldn't necessarily sound amiss if one or more previously mentioned people simply worked in the field of music. *[Janet's father was a classical composer, and her mother played violin.] Janet, **herself a singer,** often told people that she came from a musical family*

Comment: In the context that Lisa Marie was Elvis's daughter, both effectively mean the same - 'she too was a singer' and 'she herself was a singer [like her father]'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - definitely agree on this one. There's an element of 'also ran' considering who her father & one-time husband were, vs 'dad played cello in the school orchestra as a child' opposite extreme. [This is probably not a scenario that is going to crop up a lot, ie the relative fame & overall accomplishment of her family.]

Comment: @Tetsujin: There's a potentially interesting illustration here of how much better *real* (spoken) language is than written texts. My "Janet" example naturally puts stress on ***singer***, since neither parent is a singer. But if at least one parent *was* a singer, we'd just stress ***herself*** instead. And even if we change the word order to ***a singer herself,*** that same mechanism works unchanged. I don't think you can easily mimic *that* in writing!

Answer (score 1):

No.

"*Herself a singer*" implies someone else mentioned within the context is a singer as well, or failed or had aspirations as such. As an isolated sentence it doesn't make sense to use it.

Comment: The lack of article with *hospital* could just be British usage.

Comment: @stangdon I didn't know that, but I do realize now it could be headlinese. Thank for the heads-up!

Comment: @Joachim, yes, her father mentioned within the context is a singer as well.

Comment: @yunus In that case they have the same meaning, but you should have included that in the question :) (a source is also always good to mention).

Comment: 'Herself' works, but once you have context I think 'also' is far more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, _rushed to hospital_ is British usage (not just headlinese).